# How do i download Socket.io to cPanel?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cpanel

I have worked with `Socket.io` and `NodeJs` on localhost,now i want to test it on my website.I want to know how can i download `Node.js` and `Socket.io` to `cPanel`